# How to set image in circle in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

How can i make i circle picture with swift ?

My ViewController :

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class FriendsViewController : UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var profilPicture: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        profilPicture = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    }
}
```

My `profilPicture = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))` do nothing ..

Exemple: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

Comment: What does "set image in circle" mean? Can you describe more precisely what you want to do? Perhaps draw a picture of the results you want?

Comment: `profilPicture = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))` does not "do nothing". It definitely does something! But what it does is rather unfortunate. It creates a UIImageView and assigns it to a weak reference. The image view is empty; it has no image. Moreover, the reference is weak, so the image view vanishes immediately in a puff of smoke. It's hard to see from this code what you imagined would happen here.

Comment: I want to make this result : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

Comment: So, now you've added a link to a tutorial that tells you how to do it. So just follow the instructions in that tutorial! You've answered your own question.

Comment: I work in swift when i do the instructions in the tutoriel nothing append :S

Answer (score 253, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    image.layer.borderWidth = 1
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.height/2
    image.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

If you want it on an extension

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    
    func makeRounded() {
        
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

That is all you need....

Comment: that `image.clipsToBounds = true` was exactly what I needed :-)

Comment: It doesn't work if UIImageView can grow or shrink due to constrains. In that case it must be inside viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: I found that adding the border around the rounded image leaves a ghost of the original rectangle on the screen.  This was visible on Simulator 10.0 and may not occur on a real device, but thought it was significant enough to mention here.

Comment: `image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor`

turns into 

`image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor`

Comment: Work perfect in swift 4. 

Comment: You may need to use DispatchQueue:  `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:{
            self.imageview.makeRounded() })`

Answer (score 40):

You can simple create extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {

   func setRounded() {
      let radius = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2
      self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
      self.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }
}
```

and use it as below:

```
imageView.setRounded()
```

Answer (score 16):

Based in the answer of @DanielQ

**Swift 4 and Swift 3**

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {

    func setRounded() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = (self.frame.width / 2) //instead of let radius = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

You can use it in any `ViewController` with:

```
imageView.setRounded()
```

Answer (score 12):

If you mean you want to make a UIImageView circular in Swift you can just use this code:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: If you don't do ``image.clipsToBounds = true``, the image will not scale.

Comment: @Tom Spee when I set the corner radius to half the pictures width, I am getting a diamond shaped image and not a ircle. Any idea why this would be??

Comment: @user2363025 I suspect you've figured it out by now, but have you confirmed you used the *imageView* and not the *image*?

Comment: @ScottCorscadden sorry Scott, I don't have the old code to look back on.

Comment: A bit late maybe but a diamond shape can be caused by auto layout so might be that you need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if this helps anyone but I was struggling with this problem for awhile, none of the answers online helped me. For me the problem was I had different heights and widths set on the image in storyboard. I tried every solution on stack and it turns out it was something as simple as that. Once I set them both to 200 my circle profile image was perfect. This was code then in my VC.

```
profileImage2.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage2.frame.size.width/2
    profileImage2.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. This should be the answer. Two clean lines of code. No need to extend classes or anything extra.

Answer (score 6):

This way is the least expensive way and always keeps your image view rounded:

```
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        assert(bounds.height == bounds.width, "The aspect ratio isn't 1/1. You can never round this image view!")

        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
    }
}
```

The other answers are telling you to make views rounded based on frame calculations set in a `UIViewController`s `viewDidLoad()` method. **This isn't correct**, since it isn't sure what the final frame will be.

Comment: Suggest might as well add @IBDesignable

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift 4**:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {

func makeRounded() {
    let radius = self.frame.width/2.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above couldn't solve the problem in my case. My `ImageView` was placed in a customized `UITableViewCell`. Therefore I had also call the `layoutIfNeeded()` method from here. Example:

```
 class NameTableViewCell:UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate { ...

 override func awakeFromNib() {

    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    profileImageView.layoutIfNeeded()

    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let square = profileImageView.frame.size.width < profileImageView.frame.height ? CGSize(width: profileImageView.frame.size.width, height: profileImageView.frame.size.width) : CGSize(width: profileImageView.frame.size.height, height:  profileImageView.frame.size.height)
    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct CircleImage: View {
    var image: Image

    var body: some View {
        image
           .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

This is correct for `SwiftUI`

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UIImageView{
   
// Round Image
    func roundCorner() {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set equal width and height for getting Circular ImageView.Below I set width and height as 100,100.If you want to set equal width and height according to your required size,set here.

```
 var imageCircle = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
```

Then you need to set height/2 for corner radius

```
 imageCircle.layer.cornerRadius = imageCircle.frame.size.height/2
 imageCircle.layer.borderWidth = 1
 imageCircle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
 imageCircle.clipsToBounds = true
 self.view.addSubview(imageCircle)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift3/Swift4 Developers:

```
let radius = yourImageView.frame.width / 2
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = radius
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: not quite, I think he's adding an extension to ImageView. This is changing the instance of the class directly. If it's not helpful I can take it down.

Answer (score 1):

For Rounded Image, Only following code would be enough in Extension:

self.layoutIfNeeded() // in case of **autolayout**(mentioned by Tom Spee in the comment).

And also make sure the property of UIImageView **contentMode** should be set correctly to get the result.
In my case it is:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


extension UIImageView {
    func setRounded() {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
            self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// code to make the image round


import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
public func maskCircle(anyImage: UIImage) {


    self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.clipsToBounds = true




    // make square(* must to make circle),
    // resize(reduce the kilobyte) and
    // fix rotation.
    //        self.image = prepareImage(anyImage)
}
}
```

// to call the function from the view controller

```
self.imgCircleSmallImage.maskCircle(imgCircleSmallImage.image!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height/2
imageView.clipToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -1):

If your image is rounded, it would have a height and width of the exact same size (i.e 120). You simply take half of that number and use that in your code (image.layer.cornerRadius = 60).