# Why would not UIImageview be the perfect circle?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

```
let radius = self.bounds.width / 2
self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I applied the above code
But it creates a strange shape.

[image]

I do not know why and how to fix it.;;

Comment: You should make sure your width and height are the same and corner radius should be half of that value

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Shouldn't radius be half of the width/height `let radius = self.bounds.width / 2`?

Comment: I already applied a 1: 1 ratio. But it comes out like that.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wanna make perfect round view must be square.

And if your view have aspect ratio then apply corner radius after all constraints loaded for view.

For that you can apply radius view into `viewDidAppear` method.
Or   `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.
or apply radius using delay.

**Update**

```
func delay(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: The things in  viewcontroller are resolved by applying them to the viewdidappear. But how do you do things in a tableview cell?

Comment: their is `layoutSubviews` method for that.

Answer (score 3):

if width and height are equal this code works fine, change 2.5 to 2

```
let radius = self.bounds.width / 2
self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: if width and height are **not** equal, how we handle this scenario....?

Comment: @Anbu.karthik we won't get a perfect circle if width and height are not equal

Comment: Sorry, that 's not the 2.5, but the 2 applied. 
I corrected the question.

Comment: @ Shezad - plz add the code for if width and height are not equal scenario

Comment: @hoyeongkim still you are not getting a perfect circle??

Comment: @Shezad If the width and height aren't equal then it isn't a circle, it is an elipse.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik if width and height are not equal you can't make a perfect circle or else you have to change the width or height to equal size

Comment: Yes, it still looks the same.

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan I already applied a 1: 1 ratio. But it comes out like that

Comment: @Shezad would you share with us about `self.bounds.width` and `self.bounds.height` value

Comment: @hoyeongkim so i think issue with your constraints, how you are setting constraints?

Comment: @Shezad - we can do with the help of beizerpath,

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes you can

Comment: @Anbu.karthik why don't you post the answer or link the duplicate? :D

Comment: I'm trying to apply the solutions you've given me.

Comment: The things in the general view controller are resolved by applying them to the viewdidappear. But I am not sure how to solve it in the tableview cell

Comment: @hoyeongkim try to use the extension in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259630/8536028

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - thanks for valuable point, the ?'er posted the good answer also, but problem is constraint here, I am waiting for some different answer, but no body posted.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik if the problem is with constraint, you should give a fixed equal constraint or you should change it to an equal constraint.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik you could use self.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.width) above the code to convert it to equal width and height, but i don't suggest this because it's not a good method

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes that is why i asked for the rest of the code. He probably has scale aspect to fit, but the imageView is not a square. But OP isn't posting the code _sigh_

Comment: I think I got the wrong value from self.bound.frame
but, It works well because it's declared in viewdidappear. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

To make `UIImageView` circle you need to make sure you `UIImageView`'s Height and Width should me same(square).

Use divide by 2 instead of 2.5:

```
let radius = self.bounds.width / 2
```

Comment: Why is 2.5 applied?

Comment: @hoyeongkim It should be 2 instead of 2.5. i have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, that 's not the 2.5, but the 2 applied;;

Comment: @hoyeongkim so `self.bounds.width / 2` is not working for you?

Comment: Yes, it still looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1
imgView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imgView.layer.borderColor = UIcolor.black.cgColor
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
imgView.clipsToBounds = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

try this code or may be your code is perfect just put `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in your code

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the image height and width are same

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let radius = yourImageOutlet.bounds.width / 2
    yourImageOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    yourImageOutlet.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```