# how to create view like image attached . Last seen user profile image show in this

Tags: swift, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEGAw.jpg)

Last seen user profile image show in this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set image in circle in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074679/how-to-set-image-in-circle-in-swift)

Comment: Have you tried searching that? I'm sure you'll find related question on SO itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create UIImageView's with same width and height. then set the corner radius = width/2
- Set the layer border color to white and set layer border width to some value that suits the white border.
- Above two points will give you circular imageViews. Make as many as you need
- Take a parent UIView . Add the UIImageView's as subviews on that parent view from left to right with enough padding that suits your need. this will create the overlapping effect of the profile icons - like the ones in the image

Answer (score 0):

1- First make Horizontol UIStackView  of height whatever you want to be your circle and set constraint for leading and top space.

2- Make a view of width and height(what you want) and set corner radius of half to the width or heigh.

3- Make UIView border width of 2 to 3 and border color white.

4- Set spacing to -5 of StackView

Repeate **1-3 Steps** to make many view you want.

Add image in these view or buttons whatever you want. You have a view you can place anything in this view now for make it clickable.